# override ToString() with override and new keyword

Tags: c#, oop, overriding

I am new in c#.confuse with this question.

I Have override ToString() with override and new keyword.both are give me same output.then what is the difference between both.

here is my Example

```
class A
{
    public new string ToString()
    {
        return "With New Keyword";
    }
}
class B
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "With Override Keyword";
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());

        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

### Output

With New Keyword

With Override Keyword

I know its a silly question.
please anyone help me to give me difference between both methods.

I am not asking about difference between new and override key word.I want to know that difference between both method.In concept of Override Object methods.

Comment: `I am try to understand the basic of C#` isnt that what books, tutors and tutorials are for?

Comment: @Plutonix I have edited my question.I am not good with English so I have write like this.

Comment: If ever you've read the content of the documentation but still get confused, I advise you to understand the different OOP terminologies such as `extend`.

Comment: I have read that every Class is extend the Object class.So we can use new And override in both like above in all method? and it give me a same output?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado it mean we can override all method of Object class using new and Override? right

Comment: You need to read about inheritance, override and overloading concepts. If you read it properly you will have the answer of the question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords

Comment: @D-Shih I am not asking that difference between new and override.I am asking that Object class is extend in all class. Then we can override all method of object class using new and override keyword right.

Comment: both give me same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes a difference when you do this:

```
object a = new A(); // notice the type of the variable here!
object b = new B();
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
```

`a.ToString()` will not call your implementation of `ToString` and will instead call `object.ToString`, which returns the fully qualified type name of the object. `b.ToString()` *will* call your implementation.

What you did in `B` is called overriding. What you did in `A` is called *hiding*. Hiding loses its effect when the compile time type of a variable is not that type anymore. Your implementation of `ToString` will only be called when the compile time type is `A`.

Learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier).

Comment: it means if we assign over Instance to based class(Object) than Only it will make a difference other wise it is same. right?

Comment: @PravinTukadiya Exactly.

Comment: Thanks I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily google this.

**From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords)**

> In C#, a method in a derived class can have the same name as a method
>   in the base class. You can specify how the methods interact by using
>   the new and override keywords. The override modifier extends the base
>   class method, and the new modifier hides it. The difference is
>   illustrated in the examples in this topic.
>
> In a console application, declare the following two classes, BaseClass
>   and DerivedClass. DerivedClass inherits from BaseClass.

Comment: it means both are same in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In class `B` you are overriding `ToString()` method that is `Object.ToString()` because you have not inherited `A`. Now consider below example,

```
class A
{
    public string ReturnString()
    {
       return "ClassA::Method";
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public newstring ReturnString()
    {
        return "ClassB::Method";
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Here you are hiding the method in `class B` as you have inherited `Class A`. So you will get the output as `ClassA::Method` for both method calls.

Now consider below example

```
class A
{
    public virtual string ReturnString()
    {
       return "ClassA::Method";
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public override string ReturnString()
    {
        return "ClassB::Method";
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Here we have overridden the `Class A's` method in `Class B`. This means `ClassB method` is like extension or you can say it has different meaning than `ClassA`. You will get output like below

```
ClassA::Method
ClassB::Method
```